# knapsack-like algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, division

Here is a very interesting java problem I've found:

Before book printing was found the books were copied by certain people called "writers".
The bookkeeper has a stack of N books that need to be copied.For that purpose he has K writers. Each book can have a different number of pages and every writer can only take books from the top of the stack (if he takes book 1 then he can take book 2 but not book 4 or book 5). The bookkeeper knows the number of pages each book has and he needs to share the books between the writers in order for the maximum number of pages a writer has to copy to be the minimum possible.The pages of course can't be split for example you can't have a 30 page book split into 15 and 15.

For example if we have 7 books with 3 writers and the books pages accordingly: 30 50 5 60 90 5 80 then the optimal solution would be for the first writer to take the first 4 books, the second writer the next book and the 3rd the last two books so we would have:

1st = 145 pages 
2nd = 90 pages 
3rd = 85 pages

So the program is to write an algorithm which finds the optimal solution for sharing the pages between the writers. So in the end of the program you have to show how many pages each one got.

This was in a programming contest years ago and I wanted to give it a try and what I've found so far is that if you take the total number of pages of all the books and divide them by the number of writers you get in the example 106.66 pages and then you try to give to each writer the continuous books from the stack that are closest to that number, but that doesn't work well at all for large page numbers especially if the number of pages a book has exceeds the total number of pages divided by the number of writers

So share your opinion and give tips and hints if you'd like, mathematical or whatever, this is a very interesting algorithm to be found!

Comment: "So the program is to write an algorithm which finds the optimal solution for sharing the pages between the writers."

Comment: in other words which books go to which writer but the pages are what it matters the most so how many pages each one will have in the end

Comment: @SiliconTouch: So you're asking for someone to write the algorithm for you?

Comment: No I did not, I said to share opinions exactly as I did in my previous post with a "smart" algorithm

Comment: @SilliconTouch: If there are 2 writers and 3 books, I understand writer1 **cannot** take books 1&3, and writer 2 takes book 2 - is it correct?

Comment: According to the faq the "share your opinion"-questions are not good because it's difficult to find a "correct answer".

Comment: @amit no, writer1 can take book1 and if it's possible book2 as well or even book3 as well, but in order for writer 2 to take book2 then writer1 needs to have taken book1 and stopped at taking any more books in order of writer 2 to start taking continuous books from the stack

Comment: Also, how come the first has 85 pages? isn't it 150? [30+50+70]? Same goes for writer 3 in the example. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @amit sorry I did a mistake there, editing now

Comment: Btw: your example is wrong (at this writing it states:30 50 5 60 90 5 80->85/150/85 when the correct answer is 145/90/85) as I understand the problem.

Comment: @esej yes you are totally right, I actually translated the problem from my language and used one of my own examples I will re-edit it now and yes you have understood the problem correctly

Comment: -1 for not showing any effort done

Comment: I actually said what my efford was and it was quite some hours of effort, even discussed it with my mathematician but I didn't bother posting my solution because it never worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a straight forward solution, perhaps not very efficient, but the logic works. Basically you start with the number of writers being the same number as that of the number of books and reduce until you have your number of writers.

To show with an example. Suppose you start with your seven values, 30 50 5 60 90 5 80. For each step you reduce it by one by summing up the "lowest pair". The values in bold are the pair being carried on to the next iteration.

7
30 **50 5** 60 90 5 80
6
30 55 60 90 **5 80**
5
**30 55** 60 90 85
4
**85 60** 90 85
3
145 90 85

With some pseudo programming, this example shows how it could be implemented

```
main(books: { 30 50 5 60 90 5 80 }, K: 3)

define main(books, K)
  writers = books
  while writers.length > K do
    reduceMinimalPair(writers)
  endwhile
end

define reduceMinimalPair(items)
  index = 0
  minvalue = items[0] + items[1]
  for i in 1..items.length-1 do
    if items[i] + items[i + 1] < minvalue then
      index = i
      minvalue = items[i] + items[i + 1]
    endif
  endfor
  items.removeat(index)
  items.removeat(index + 1)
  items.insertat(index, minvalue)
end
```

Comment: this actually looks like it could work, in java though I would have to implement this with a list not an array as i was thinking (because you have to remove items as well). Am I correct?

Comment: @SilliconTouch: Yes, you would replace two items with one. An array *could* work, but you'd end up with more work since you would have to shift the values from the higher indexes to the lower ones. A list should work the best in this example.

Comment: when a question is under java tag try to answer with java code only

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you have books 1...n with pages b1,b2,...,bn. Assume you have K writers.

Initialize a matrix F[1...n,1...K]=infinity.

Let F[i,1]= sum_j=1..i (bj)

Now, for every k=2..K

F[i,k] = min_j=1..i( max(F[j,k-1], sum_r=j+1..i (br) )

Comment: I read about the Knapsack Problem but what you say just seem quite confusing for me as I don't know about dynamic programming. I am a college student and I haven't been taught dynamic programming yet, so I would be glad if you could explain it just a little bit more

Comment: @SilliconTouch I am sorry. I did not realize that you can only allocate consecutive block of books to each writer. I have updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: yes I saw your updated solution as well and that is the part I can't really understand...

Comment: this is soooo confusing for my little brain but I really appreciate your help

Comment: @SilliconTouch Now I am almost giving the exact program!

Comment: if i understand this correctly, let's say we have 7 books and 2 writers with pages: [30 50 5 60 90 5 80]. What you are saying is in the F[7,2] matrix the first column would be this: [30 80 85 145 235 240 320]. Am I correct so far?

Comment: Also I would guess your matrixes start from index 1 because in java the first index is 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you thought is the right one, but if you are saying it did not work for big numbers then maybe you should check if a bigger number than the average exists and do something else in that case. Maybe remove the number and give it from the start to a writer or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to solving it with Dynamic Programming, you can also binary search a upper page limit that everyone will not copy more than this number of pages. When this number converge, that's the answer.

Comment: So you mean find the most pages someone could copy and not let anyone go over that limit? If so how is it possible to find that number? You say binary search but I only know how to use binary search to find a number in an array for example. How do I use binary search to find the most pages a writer would copy?

Comment: you guess a number and test whether it's possible that no one copy more than this number of pages and finish the books. There's a number X that all numbers smaller than X is not possible and all number larger than or equal to X is possible. You binary search the X.